# Difference quotient for functions of bounded variation

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N$, $u \in BV(\mathbb{R}^N)$, be a function of bounded variation. 
We have that the following holds

> $$(\ast) \qquad \frac{1}{|B_r(0)|}\int_{B_r(0)} \frac{|u(x+z)-u(x)-Az|}{|z|} dz =0$$
>   for the points where $Du$ is not singular, where $A$ is the approximate differential of $u$.

What happens in the points where $Du$ is singular? What should replace $A$ to still get convergence of that integral to $0$?

Comment: I don't think that your question is quite correct. For example if $u$ is linear (at least in a small neighborhood of $z$), then $[u(x+z)-u(x)]/|z| = A z / |z|$ has integral zero over $B_r (0)$, simply because the integrand is odd. But the differential would be $A$, which does not have to be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the following is true:

> **Theorem.** If $u\in BV(\mathbb{R}^N)$, then for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$: $$
>  \frac{1}{|B_r(0)|}\int_{B_r(0)}\left|\frac{u(x+z)-u(x)-[Du(x)]_{ac}z}{r}\right|^{\frac{N}{N-1}}\,
>  dz\to 0 \quad \text{as $r\to 0$.} $$

Here $[Du(x)]_{ac}$ is the density of the absolutely continuous part of the distributional derivative $Du$ which, by the definition of $BV$ is a Radon measure.

In fact the above convergence holds for all $x$ such that:

1. $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $u$,
2. Lebesgue point of $Du$,
3. $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{[Du]_s(B(x,r))}{r^n}=0$$

where $[Du]_s$ is the singular part of $Du$.

For other points you need not have concergence no matter what linear operator $A$ you take.

Moreover,
$[Du]_{ac}$ equals almost everywhere to the approximate derivative of $u$ at all points at which the above convergence to zero holds.

The above results is proven in **Evans and Gariepy**, *Measure theory and fine properties of functions.*, Theorems 1 and 4 in Chapter 6.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "For other points you need not have concergence no matter what linear operator $A$ you take." --- that's the key point for me. What about if we take a nonlinear operator. Is there one such that we have convergence to $0$?

Comment: @Dal That is not a well stated problem. If you take a nonlinear operator $Az=u(x+z)-u(x)$, then clearly you have convergence to zero so you need to be more specific what nonlinear operators you want to consider.

Comment: A kind of approximate derivative for non-Lebesgue singular points.

Comment: @Dal Derivative, approximate or not should be linear in $z$.

Comment: So having convergence to $0$ in the case of singular point is hopeless?

Comment: @Dal It is hard to say if it is hopeless, but I would not expect any interesting results along the convergence you consider.

Comment: Alright. Thanks again.